# How to place Blender model in Unity using script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, blender

I made Blender model and dragged it in assets folder(.blend, not FBX). Now I do something like

```
var robot = GameObject.Instantiate (Resources.Load("robot")) as GameObject;
robot.transform.position = new Vector3 (description.X, description.IsRound ? description.ZSize : description.ZSize / 2f, description.Y);
robot.AddComponent<Rigidbody> ();
robot.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
robot.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (description.XSize, description.ZSize, description.YSize);
robot.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, (float)description.Yaw.Grad, 0);
robot.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (30, 30, 30);
```

But when I try to launch it I get nothing in scene. If I use cube for example

```
var robot = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
```

I get cube. My questions is how to properly load blender model and create GameObject from it?

Comment: Is there a specific reason reason why you are using `Resources.Load` instead of a reference to the prefab?

Comment: Also, please elaborate on exact meaning of "I get nothing in scene". Don't you get any errors? Is there a new game object in the scene hierarchy?

Comment: I use 'Resource.Load' because I found this option on the Internet and I don't understand how to use prefab's reference. I don't get any errors, just empty scene. And yes, there is no any objects in scene hierarchy.

Comment: OK, so I must ask even more basic question: is there any particular reason you are doing this in code instead of creating a prefab in the editor?

Comment: Yes, I can't use editor because this is a part of code which generates arena with robots for competition and it should be automated.

Comment: What about all the parameters, don't you want to just load prefab at runtime, instead of manually adding ` Rigidbody` component, for example?

Comment: I think that I can do it, I mean - pack all of these things into one prefab. But my problem is connected with Blender. I can't understand how to simply change primitive cube to model.

Answer (score 0):

`Resources` are used to load assets dynamically downloaded from the web. If you already have an asset or prefab in the project, you can just link to the prefab/model file in the Assets folder from the script in the editor.

```
public GameObject Model; // set it in the editor
void SomeMethod()
{
    var robot = GameObject.Instantiate (Model) as GameObject;
    robot.transform.position = new Vector3 (description.X, description.IsRound ? description.ZSize : description.ZSize / 2f, description.Y);
    robot.AddComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    robot.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
    robot.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (description.XSize, description.ZSize, description.YSize);
    robot.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, (float)description.Yaw.Grad, 0);
    robot.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (30, 30, 30);
}
```

Comment: I have blender model in assets, how to properly set it in Model?

Comment: Do you have an asset file in your Assets folder?

Comment: So, expose a public field in a script, and just drag and drop the file from you assets panel in unity editor intro the property field of the behaviour attached to the object.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to export the object from blender as an fbx file (delete the camera and the light from the scene)
2. Drag it in the assets folder and transform it into an prefab
3. In Unity create a publci GAmeObject and drag the prefab in the script
4. USe this line to place it: Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0f,0f,0f), Quaternion.identity);